# Share testing data between 2 rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, integration-testing, factory-bot

In our company project, we have 2 Rails projects: A and B share the same database but different models. My boss doesn't allow me extract the models to a gem / rails engine for both projects because I'm new member and it takes many risks for our production. So I have to keep it as currently. I've researched a lot of things but still doesn't have solution at the moment. Let's me summarize:

Project A usually used to create and save data to database so that the models in A always up-to-date. Project B is used to load data so that project B doesn't have all the models as A and some models in B have lack associations. My mission is adding tests for project B. This is my solution:

First of all, I share one database test for both projects.

Secondly, in project A, I setup Factory Girl to create test data.

So the question is that from project B, how can I call or trigger project A to run the A's Factory Girl in order to create test data so that project B could load that data and verify it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can write rake tasks which basically run one-off scripts in your application and can be triggered from the command line.

```
rails g task my_task_name
```

This will create a file `lib/tasks/my_task_name.rake`. Writing rake tasks is pretty simple:

```
namespace :my_namespace do
  task :my_app => :environment do
    # create some db records here
  end
end
```

which you'd call like `rake my_namespace:my_app`

The use a namespace is optional, but the `=> :environment` part is important - that's what loads up the code from your rails application.

When you run a rake task is will look in the `lib/tasks` folder of whatever repo you're in.

Comment: I assume that your suggestion is creating rake task in project A for populating data to testing database. However, how can I call A's rake task from B side ?

Comment: Could you give an example to call A's rake from B project? I still don't find the example in this case. Thanks